# delete in laravel with get using Route::resource()

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I'm trying to delete in laravel using GET instead of DELETE because my shared server doesn't support DELETE verb.

So, I used [Jeffrey Way's method](https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/5112282)

Thing is in my routes.php, I use

```
 Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

For example.

So, When I use GET instead of DELETE with resource, system think I will use show method, instead of destroy method.

The only way I see to do that is not using resource method to route, and detail all my routes, but I don't like it, it is kind of heavy to read.

Is it any way to keep using resource() and have a customized route to destroy?

Tx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML forms don't actually support `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE` actions; they only support `GET` or `POST` requests.

Instead, Laravel spoofs the method to allow you to use these using a hidden `_method` field, which you can read up on in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing).

Using `Route::resource` will automatically route `DELETE` methods to your `destroy` function in the controller.

If you are using [Form helpers](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html), then you can use the following in your `Form::open()` to specify the delete method:

`{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE']) !!}`

If you aren't then you can simply include it like so `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` inside your HTML form.

If you don't spoof it and use a `GET` request then the `Route::resource` will associate this with the `show` function in your controller.

**Using a button to do this**

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: I use a link not a form: <a href="{!! URL::action('PlaceController@destroy',  $place->id) !!}" data-method="delete" data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">delete</a>

Comment: You can't use a link, it has to be a form - but you can do something else to make it appear as a button - example above in edit.

Comment: I stand corrected, either way given you are sending a `GET` request when you click on the link it won't be picked up by the `Route::resource`.

Comment: nop. the only way I found not to describe all routes is inserting delete code inside show method, and add extra route if I need showing details of my object... that's why I wrote this post

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `Route::resource` with `except` parameter and customize excepted routes as desired.

Example:

`Route::resource('product, 'ProductController', ['except' => ['destroy']]);
Route::get('product/{id}/destroy','ProductController@destroy');`

Haven't found better solution yet.