# Edit page show blank in laravel

Tags: php, windows, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have news details inserted and i need to show it on the edit page but when i try to edit and delete  it shows blanks page insert and show is working properly. i have been stucked on this from morning. id is getting from the database but it shows a blank page,Not using any Form helper

1.what's problem,is it on route file 
  2.is it on Controller file

route.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('books','BookController');
Route::resource('news','NewsController');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/news','NewsController@index')->name('news');
//Route::get('/news/create','NewsController@create');
//Route::get('/news/edit','NewsController@edit');
```

Edit.blade.php

```
 @extends('theme.default')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    NEW BEE NEWS DETAILS
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <form method="post" action="{{route('news.update',[$news->id])}}"
                                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>NEWS TITLE</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="atitle" id="atitle" class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="PLEASE ADD TITLE OF NEWS" value="{{$news->name}}">
                                    <p class="help-block">Example: SELFY PLAYSHARE </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>NEWS</label>
                                    <textarea name="news" id="news" class="form-control" {{$news->news}}></textarea>
                                    <p class="help-block">DETAILED NEWS HERE</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>NEWS LINK</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="alink" id="alink" class="form-control"
                                           placeholder="PLEASE ADD LINK OF NEWS" value="{{$news->alink}}">
                                    <p class="help-block">Example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/selfyplusure</p>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>NEWS IMAGE</label>
                                    <input type="file" name="addimage" id="addimage" value="{{$news->imagename}}">
                                </div>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">ADD NEWS</button>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

NewsController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\News;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NewsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $news = News::all();
        return view('news.index', ['news' => $news]);
    }


    public function create()
    {
        return view('news.create');
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {

            $news=new News();

            if($request->hasFile('addimage')){

                $request->file('addimage');
                $imagename=$request->addimage->store('public\newsimage');
                $news->name = $request->input('atitle');
                $news->alink = $request->input('alink');
                $news->news = $request->input('news');
                $news->imagename = $imagename;
                $news->save();
                if($news) {

                    return $this->index();



                }   }
            else{
                return back()->withInput()->with('error', 'Error Creating News ');
            }


    }


    public function show(News $news)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit(News $news)
    {
        $news=News::findOrFail($news->id);
        return view('news.edit',['News'=>$news]);
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $news = News::findOrFail($id);
        // update status as 1
        $news->status = '1';
        $news->save();
        if ($news) {
            // insert datas as new records
            $newss = new News();
            //On left field name in DB and on right field name in Form/view
            $newss->name = $request->input('atitle');
            $newss->alink = $request->input('alink');
            $newss->news = $request->input('news');
            $newss->imagename = $request->input('addimage');
            $newss->save();
            if ($newss) {
                return $this->index();

            }
        }
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $news = News::findOrFail($id);
        $news->status = '-1';
        $news->save();
        if ($news) {
            return $this->index();
        }
        else{
            return $this->index();
        }
    }
}
```

Link to delete and Edit

```
 <td><a href="/news/{{$news->id}}"><input type="button" name="edit" value="EDIT"> </a>
  <td><a href="/news/{{$news->id}}"><input type="button" name="delete" value="DELETE"></a></td>
```

Comment: show us the code of the link to edit and delete page

Comment: also check Edit.blade Case sensitiveness try news.Edit in the return

Comment: Edit page is already there and when i click on delete button it should delete

Comment: how do u go to edit page
the href  code???

Comment: No it's not working @Jigs1212

Comment: where is the href code ??
how do u navigate to edit page

Comment: I have updated the question please check on the bottom of the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete in laravel with get using Route::resource()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747583/delete-in-laravel-with-get-using-routeresource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the link to edit

```
<td><a href="/news/{{$news->id}}/edit"><input type="button" name="edit" value="EDIT"> </a>
```

For delete please go through 
[Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747583/delete-in-laravel-with-get-using-routeresource)

Comment: Thank you happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try to use this.

return view('news.edit',compact('news'));

Comment: ok if you are using resource method in routes then you need to use link like above mentioned 
<td><a href="/news/{{$news->id}}/edit"><input type="button" name="edit" value="EDIT"> </a>